# Pandas groupby: aggregate only on partial records

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, aggregate, pandas-groupby

I have the following data frame:

```
id   src     target     duration
001     A      C           4
001     B      C           3
001     C      C           2
002     B      D           5
002     C      D           2
```

and I used the following code to do some aggregations, which works fine.

```
df_new = df.groupby(['id','target']) \
        .apply(lambda x: pd.Series({'min_duration': min(x['duration']), \
                                    'total_duration':sum(x['duration']), \
                                    'all_src':list(x['src'])
                                   })).reset_index()
```

Now I want to compute the sum only for `src != target` records. I modified my code like below:

```
df_new = df.groupby(['id','target']) \
        .apply(lambda x: pd.Series({'min_duration': min(x['duration']), \
                                    'total_duration':sum(x['duration']), \
                                    'total_duration_condition':sum(x['duration']) if x['src'] != x['target'], \
                                    'all_src':list(x['src'])
                                   })).reset_index()
```

But then got `Invalid Syntax` error in my new line:

```
'total_duration_condition':sum(x['duration']) if x['src'] != x['target']
```

I am wondering what should be the proper way to do the sum only for part of the records? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try writing your code like below

```
df.groupby(['id','target']).apply(lambda x: pd.Series({'min_duration': min(x['duration']), \
                                    'total_duration':sum(x['duration']), \
                                    'total_duration_condition':sum(x['duration'][x['src'] != x['target']]), \# I change this part
                                    'all_src':list(x['src'])
                                   })).reset_index()
```

Change line

```
'total_duration_condition':sum(x['duration']) if x['src'] != x['target']
```

To

```
sum(x['duration'][x['src'] != x['target']])
```